# Cordova ** BUILD FAILED ** with Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been having some troubles building ionic Android app on my Mac OX el Capitan. I have installed all required sdks to my knowledge, and made sure all sdks are up-to date.

What i did

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android --stacktrace

         Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
            at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 12.849 secs

    /Users/Admin/OneDrive/Bl_11_16_15/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                        throw e;
                              ^
    Error code 1 for command: /Users/Admin/OneDrive/Bl_11_16_15/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/Admin/OneDrive/Bl_11_16_15/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
    ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/Admin/OneDrive/Bl_11_16_15/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
    Error: /Users/Admin/OneDrive/Bl_11_16_15/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
    sh-3.2#
```

Comment: did you install Apache Ant?

Comment: Thanks @Muhsin.  No I didn't install Apache Ant. Is that required?

Comment: This link will help you https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Comment: hey @Muhsin i followed that tutorial and now i'm getting this error

`Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-googleplayservices@19.0.0 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: version not found: cordova-plugin-googleplayservices@19.0.0`

Comment: did you install android sdk ?

Comment: just type android in your terminal and install all libraries

Comment: switching to a prior version of cordova-android worked for me (e.g. `cordova platform add android@2.1.0`).